# PHP get_declared_classes function weird display

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I am learning OOP PHP and in the course of my tutorials I wrote a script to display all declared classes. Here is the script:

```
<?php
class Person {

}
$classes = get_declared_classes();
foreach($classes as $class) {
    echo $class ."<br/>";
}
?>
```

This is what I get when I run the script:

```
stdClass
Exception
ErrorException
Closure
COMPersistHelper
com_exception
com_safearray_proxy
variant
com
dotnet
DateTime
DateTimeZone
DateInterval
DatePeriod
LogicException
BadFunctionCallException
BadMethodCallException
DomainException
InvalidArgumentException
LengthException
OutOfRangeException
RuntimeException
OutOfBoundsException
OverflowException
RangeException
UnderflowException
UnexpectedValueException
RecursiveIteratorIterator
IteratorIterator
FilterIterator
RecursiveFilterIterator
CallbackFilterIterator
RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator
ParentIterator
LimitIterator
CachingIterator
RecursiveCachingIterator
NoRewindIterator
AppendIterator
InfiniteIterator
RegexIterator
RecursiveRegexIterator
EmptyIterator
RecursiveTreeIterator
ArrayObject
ArrayIterator
RecursiveArrayIterator
SplFileInfo
DirectoryIterator
FilesystemIterator
RecursiveDirectoryIterator
GlobIterator
SplFileObject
SplTempFileObject
SplDoublyLinkedList
SplQueue
SplStack
SplHeap
SplMinHeap
SplMaxHeap
SplPriorityQueue
SplFixedArray
SplObjectStorage
MultipleIterator
ReflectionException
Reflection
ReflectionFunctionAbstract
ReflectionFunction
ReflectionParameter
ReflectionMethod
ReflectionClass
ReflectionObject
ReflectionProperty
ReflectionExtension
ReflectionZendExtension
SessionHandler
__PHP_Incomplete_Class
php_user_filter
Directory
SQLite3
SQLite3Stmt
SQLite3Result
ZipArchive
LibXMLError
DOMException
DOMStringList
DOMNameList
DOMImplementationList
DOMImplementationSource
DOMImplementation
DOMNode
DOMNameSpaceNode
DOMDocumentFragment
DOMDocument
DOMNodeList
DOMNamedNodeMap
DOMCharacterData
DOMAttr
DOMElement
DOMText
DOMComment
DOMTypeinfo
DOMUserDataHandler
DOMDomError
DOMErrorHandler
DOMLocator
DOMConfiguration
DOMCdataSection
DOMDocumentType
DOMNotation
DOMEntity
DOMEntityReference
DOMProcessingInstruction
DOMStringExtend
DOMXPath
PDOException
PDO
PDOStatement
PDORow
SimpleXMLElement
SimpleXMLIterator
XMLReader
XMLWriter
mysqli_sql_exception
mysqli_driver
mysqli
mysqli_warning
mysqli_result
mysqli_stmt
SoapClient
SoapVar
SoapServer
SoapFault
SoapParam
SoapHeader
tidy
tidyNode
XSLTProcessor
Collator
NumberFormatter
Normalizer
Locale
MessageFormatter
IntlDateFormatter
ResourceBundle
Transliterator
Spoofchecker
finfo
PharException
Phar
PharData
PharFileInfo
OCI-Lob
OCI-Collection
ImagickException
ImagickDrawException
ImagickPixelIteratorException
ImagickPixelException
Imagick
ImagickDraw
ImagickPixelIterator
ImagickPixel
n0s54l8h5foe
1c64czrdfv738gaft4sg
c2hn2j3fw7a
s98x918
razrohcnxv4b70qpf47zt
zk3wlx8b1tmbaotdrwcephfzs5qe_
nq5r1ph3ne19ixlrfuri
fh0llvqdyayevb90
q9qp_s9lc0lh94
8ptnfa0
nlr1i1sm40w3
1sg5w8bq
cugt
1929yx5i2nr6v
pr_sj
xqgwvh91leju
1x5db_pnu3ipda
igkk8oz7mt2tj_
09l5925x4wx3gmtub
sdniqeahcjpux7kn
1i6hqe
4d99jng8oe
ad_wnfu4gmjub9a
9fg61c68
1awm1s92clpwm
0jhc2sjx
qxea
dc3fp8zng8
m0g2s1wza
cick14n3i
05paf3myo4
qhxluh9
so2gc9rjj7
wm1kjyz_jy_
905_hu1rytxae
h190mb_pft29x_
938ao5
nbbb08_hs_zl9
p3h1d378tnk4hflb1i6t
72j7371oi
rz2skjjta
dygt8f4oeuozpei3c
b0eijpkjbenyl7f9
d5tgq4
5c1mhnk6riy_
yu0
4o1tmbxn1249
w61n5801
m1oifycqax6qao8
7557sil_lmc_vqo0rncjyohz
kp7q_utl2l8x2877pz
jkyygccr5
jh9ceo1t_lt
n73wrfihjxfyp4n
27mez9lx61ow5t9
3035m1deq20i4uxb
1_51nrfky8
5vobw7v5moiezgh
5ngx54w96bf
_3aj41a7wl17_s649t
smulvovi5fz
5d6mpsj5e7
2zc832_
zl6nmt61it
j94vimp
gnweevmq_4lxxoer
v8dydhokfdi2t5i
f_dvw5w9xvk
rhu5g0zlvyc
lhe983213lb5to3imgs
w8jknfwqj77hq95y
ah9mycq
_v4lpdho0g5qyvvgj
ca1zw8bvclh4gfpdimzi5rk
1deg558sr_y1133jaca6y
n6uzxp8awwl
jhj6zwjmlppfz
slq1p3ang0sk
czl9h4jricv
bh7gdsbvhz
vvwuxpxfq6ht7
kkkrd_tyfxs
4awi4iv
wn61t8boe
yj4x59wlfg6jtzo
r4kndj9cmvy5n2sgr0tuak
ybb6ppz_d19vxs
e7jfa9dc7o94b5ikc7bsecn
z1q84d825_mx1xbbery
qaxon48z6k7h2wcwkm
c_dszjq70ki13h24
g2wb9tm_va1hdfi
pdsut_34x1gj_vhy
6pi3c1dmz7ozz2wt8p2
23kf3t2iiliklxamu8
_5qy22cpo0577ptdzupwjg7hs6
earqhgpu_g
6q337av2k3v7ux2ahgv
_kqpis69o6cq07ey
bzqq9e4rdzjpcei8
ij1sdnxifcu5b
6nh95t2ncb3_5ldm
a4wlcpxkaz
1haar0hgs_
7kxtg_g
5knseev0
g7ckvll1
c4awfhvjy656342wm3n
muk6yj2gq_fhb2mlr
0ncm_ptrm8sdw
8aj4oaixhv_5
qo2_ih57k9gr4t6wqk8a0ix9ur
ey0633vse759cxuyl9
6sv3tcx0521611btw
z15x66ez1nj
5mqpdv806r3jz8gdk3sqvu
seoobpr1rbpag
cn005c_m_3g
uj1a15jpx90b3kgyune51
ut5rxdl5rfe_q
ou2m2cdppglgduhnb94nhb
q_lohl_bzw_1u
ijy6kcjylo8vb721
dzzuy00m0uiqqo
1w07cxhnxsvkx32a
eenn14wwu28er8sks0tsizqs
7hfgbks36i81vty
o7nm78bua9hy0
lmu2jozykxjp18
g83ecntc7a6e9hgps99le6dhl9p2wkx
ktftq457djhq829iigi1vi
6aq94zxxhdoioq4n0a7x6v7
4p99umipk153x8
c895mc_e7w6mg0az
loj0_gmn9s8qootelk6k_yj1t
mhdq9hu_4df35bvdzsdic6qj
97z1_t9hl5e49u6hi7
lm5tyfef2swcj8
4p03sq8t0he1j9wo3
h724_ah7wee3lxn34nv5
l8gf6asj773cbybi
457sa43ef4fwgqkh2ax
ggu5aox51xy_nz9
0lejuvtl0p564vbtloy52vo0
gdxynz316ghqw2x
rc7_0wfvj2_t1k5smym6u2
4ud9hce5l5x0l_fp_weii8qj
v5879zfjg267cp
m4nzo_zw02
86qgpl4d3rsd
lomwnb0jsdgi
grv13qia
o310pp
3bq
5n7o8ur
8gi6uxkn0b4e2yy4wtz
rqcy2qj1pcvt_
4gsiscns_qp1kfhc
nucsm4t
ieg04_i7wt6umz
4s1fgrzu1
zg_99b_j
java
JavaException
ZendJobQueue
ZendJobQueueException
ZendMonitorUIException
m_12512xouo00nml5rmx30
li7fc8174z6ebzn4vz6qg
j26fsgme__j_
7oevo2nqy6zm1
zaak
Person
```

There are some normal looking classes, and very many weird looking ones. Is this normal, and what does it mean? I am running this on my localhost (Zend Server Free Edition - PHP 5.4.21 on IIS 8.5). Thanks for any constructive answers.

Comment: A quick Google of some of them suggest they are from the Zend Framework. You can look up what they correspond to [here](http://www.ikt.ca/train/allfiles/chap14/getclass.php).

Comment: `echo (new ReflectionClass('lm5tyfef2swcj8'))->getFileName();` - to see where it comes from.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So, basically, it is normal to have such class names? If I may ask, how does one go about remembering such class names in order to use them, assuming I am using Zend Framework, as @GeorgeBrighton suggested they are from Zend Framework?

Comment: You don't actually use them directly. They're, for whatever reason, automatically generated classes with a random name which the program uses internally.

Comment: Thanks all. It's clearer to me now. I appreciate.